# $\left(-1\right)^0$: What is it and why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I tried to search for this question here but couldn't find any. But probably there is a good chance that someone already asked it.

> What is $\left(-1\right)^0$?

I get mixed results when I try to figure out the above in Google. Some say $-1$, others say it's a $1$. I thought that any number raised to zero is $1$.

I would like to get an intuition, if at all possible, for why $\left(-1\right)^0$ is whatever it is.

Comment: Are you asking about $(-1)^0$ or $-(1^0)$?

Comment: I edited your post to match your comment below about "having $\left(-1\right)^0$ in mind". Now people will better recognize that your concern isn't about the order of operations.

Comment: Note that $-1^0$ is interpreted as $-(1^0)$ rather than $(-1)^0$. I don't see any other reason "Some say $-1$."

Comment: @Blue cool. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're running into an order-of-operations issue: do you mean "$(-1)^0$" or "$-(1^0)$"? The former is $1$, the latter is $-1$.

I think the standard order of operations would be to do exponents first, then multiplication, so this would read as $-(1^0)$; but I think reasonable people could interpret it either way. When in doubt, use parentheses (especially since order of operations is really just convention)!

Comment: I was having  $(-1)^0$ in mind. So we treat  $-1$ just like any other number then.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

${(-a)}^0={(-a)}^{1-1}={(-a)}^1.{(-a)}^{-1}={(-a)}.\frac{1}{(-a)}=1, a\neq0$